# Astronomy doesn't show at the top of `Explore our sites`

Tags: support, status-completed, stackexchange

When logged in into stackoverflow and clicking StackExchange button on the bar( top left ), the sites where I'm a member of show before the search bar and every other site which are listed alphabetical.

This works for other sites, but not for Astronomy even though I'm a member of it. I first I though the site must not be in beta but space exploration is in beta but still shows at the top.

Comment: I assume since you deleted this that you figured it out, but just in case you didn't: the sites listed at the top are the five sites you have the most rep in--not all sites you're a member of.

Comment: @called2voyage I have 6 sites listed. But there is an answer at meta stackoverflow now http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216971/multicollider-site-switcher-not-showing-all-sites-that-i-have-accounts-on. And if I open the menu from here I get 8 sites listed.

Comment: Yes, any site you open also shows at the top. I don't know why you have six listed by default. Perhaps if you have two sites which tie for fifth place in rep they both show up? If you show me a screenshot I might be able to explain better.

Comment: It would also help if you sent a screenshot of your Stack Exchange accounts page.

Comment: I doubt it is worth the effort. Admins probably don't care about such details.

Comment: They actually do. If there is indeed an error or bug, it would be worth pointing out. I cannot help assess whether there is or not without screenshots though.

Answer (score 5):

The site switcher currently shows the current site in the first position and your top few sites (by your reputation) "above the fold".  The rest of the sites are located under the "Find a Stack Exchange site" search bar.  So even though I have an account on *every single site* my site switcher looks like this:

[image: My site switcher]

It more or less matches what I see in my flair:

[image: Flair!]

There is a planned change to allow everyone to [customize the site switcher](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215928/custom-ordering-for-stack-exchange-all-sites-dropdown), which I'm looking forward to.  I kinda don't do much gardening anymore, so that site is one I will probably drop.  A few new sites (like Astronomy) are interesting right now, so I'd like to "promote" them.

**UPDATE:** This change has now been [completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215928/custom-ordering-for-stack-exchange-all-sites-dropdown).